# What is $O(\sqrt{2^n}n^2)$?

Tags: asymptotics

What is $O(\sqrt{2^n}n^2)$?

Is it $O(2^n)$, or does the square root cause it to be reduced? I'm trying to analyze an algorithm that I came up with, and if it still has exponential time cost, I'm going to have to try harder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt {2^n}=2^{\frac n2}$, still exponential in the sense that it will dominate $n^k$ for any $k$

Comment: Furthermore $2^{\frac{n}{2}} = (\sqrt{2})^n$ and $(\sqrt{2})^n \leq 2^n$ for $n \geq 1$.